# Goaccess Process Multiple Logs

Tags: bash, goaccess

I have a directory with log files.  I want to process the last 13 of them (past quarter).  I can't use a wildcard using `Goaccess` because I don't want to include all of them, just the last 13 generated weeks' worth.

I have an array of the filenames of those last 13 files, but I don't know the syntax for the `Goaccess` command to include those files.  I can't find any reference as to how to do this, as all notes I've seen refer to using a wildcard.  I don't want to start copying and moving files around.  There should be a way of doing this in the command line with multiple filenames which I can generate just fine.

How can I use a multiple logname input syntax in `Goaccess`?

Something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/goaccess -p /users/rich/things/goaccess.conf log1.log log2.log log3.log -o qreport.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MULTIPLE LOG FILES**

> There are several ways to parse multiple logs with GoAccess. The
>   simplest is to pass multiple log files to the command line:

`goaccess access.log access.log.1`

[goaccess-custom-logs](https://goaccess.io/man?source=post_page---------------------------#custom-log)

In your case, you need to process only the last three generated file so you can get the last three file using `ls`. The final command will become

```
/usr/local/bin/goaccess -p /users/rich/things/goaccess.conf  $(ls -t log* | head -3 | tr '\r\n' ' ') -o qreport.html
```

This will process the last three files that is started with `log`

Comment: Ah I grabbed the filenames using `Ruby`, but yes, I was after the `-f` syntax which works.  I don't know how I didn't find that.  I checked that FAQ page.  Thank you.